# text/string issue in jquery with html controls

Tags: jquery, html, string

i have a formatted text saved in database.there are spaces,bold text,line break etc etc in my text.when i get from database and alert it,it is ok,all is same.BUT when i assign it to an html control like

```
<textarea id="description"></textarea>
```

and then alert it,it loses all its html tags like space,line breaks bold etc etc...whole text shows as one paragraph.

```
  <textarea name="description" cols="200" rows="50" id="description"></textarea>
  alert(json.description_demo);//this is ok
  $("#description").val(json.description_demo);
  alert($("#description").val());//now it give me issue
```

## What can be the issue?here is my text

Brand new!!!

Huge size of 3 bedroom apartment located in Dubai Marina Orra tower for rent

Situated on high floor, overlooking a gorgeous view of Marina

Recreation and sports amenities - Temperature controlled swimming pools, Jacuzzi, Separate wet areas for his/hers, state of the art gymnasium, Tennis & Basketball courts and dedicated indoor children play area
Facilities:

24/7 reception and security
Swimming pool
Gym
Sauna
Childrens play area
Luxurious interior design
High speed lifts
Accessible to Marina Mall, Emirates Mall and Ibn Batuta Mall, only 3 minutes

Click this link for The Dubai Marina virtual tour :http://360emirates.com/virtual_tours/15#

Rhhh Real Estate provides full service to each and every clientele. We offer comprehensive properties for sale and rentals. Our team is highly adept property consultants who are experts in every aspect of the real estate industry.

For further details on this property please contact Roassasae Real Estate, ORN: 121

Tel:  +97142

Mob: +971544444444
To view more properties visit www.abc.ae

To list your properties contact us now and a well designed marketing package awaits for you.
RERA Broker ID- 13334

Comment: Form elements are different from usual elements, in that they cannot have any elements as descendants. When you insert HTML into a textarea, it is displayed as just that, HTML. The markup isn't parsed into elements.

Comment: your code works by itself [http://jsfiddle.net/3gjPn/](http://jsfiddle.net/3gjPn/)

Comment: i have update text in your jsfiddle

Comment: There's no HTML markup in your example text.

Comment: please see above text,this is written in tinymce and now want to edit again there...before i assign to tinymce,it is not like what i have in db.

Comment: You can give the <pre> tag a try if you want to keep the format of your text

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [contenteditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) div :

```
<div id="description" contenteditable="true">

</div>
```

With as javascript :

```
$("#description").html(json.description_demo);
```

But be careful about XSS attacks ;).

Comment: json.description_demo is plain text ?!

Comment: plain text created with tinymcs...see above text,it is example

Comment: See the difference between plain text and html in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ns6bu/1/) — your code is working fine

Comment: i am using $("#description").val(json.description_demo); but still not working....surely i am using plain text

Comment: Though you wanted formated text. From where does your json.description_demo comes from ?
Try appending the same text in a div with `$('#div').text(json.description_demo);` and watch if it's works.

Comment: this is ok when i try alert($("#div").text();Issue is i want to assign to textarea which is editor for tinymce.with textarea it give issue